# Given $A \in M_{4 \times 4}(\mathbb{Q})$ such that $A^7=I$, how many similarity classes of $A$ are there?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

I'm trying to work thrpough some similarity class problems for linear algebra, and I came across the following problem. Given $A \in M_{4 \times 4}(\mathbb{Q})$ such that $A^7=I$, how many similarity classes of $A$ are there?

I mainly have a question regarding the fact that we are over $\mathbb{Q}$, and not $\mathbb{C}$.  Do we still know if the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^7-1$?  If so, then don't we still conclude that $A$ only has one similarity class, since $x^7-1$ has all simple roots (albeit only one of them is in $\mathbb{Q}$)?

Or do we only conclude that the minimal polynomial of $A$ has $1$ as a root, and only $1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We indeed find that the minimal polynomial of $A$ has only $1$ as a root. Moreover, we can actually deduce that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $x - 1$, which is to say that we must have $A = I$.

The minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^7 - 1$, and the minimal polynomial of $A$ must have rational coefficients. If a rational polynomial of degree at most $4$ divides $x^7 - 1$, then it must be $x - 1$ since $x^7 - 1 = (x - 1)(x^6 + x^5 + \cdots + 1)$ is an irreducible factorization. The conclusion follows.

Comment: $+1$ .The highest degree irreducible factor of $p(x) =x^7-1$ is of degree $\phi(7) =6$ . In fact $x^6+x^5+\cdots+x+1$ is the $7$th Cyclotomoic polynomial $\Phi_7(x) $.